# ImportModuleError aws lambda. Cannot find module './json.js'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, apollo-server, esbuild

I am using esbuild to bundle my lambda function.
here is my script for bundling dependencies:

```
    "scripts": {
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/esbuild src/lambdaHandler/index.js --bundle --outfile=out/index.js --platform=node --target=node12 --sourcemap --define:process.env.NODE_ENV=\\\"dev\\\"",
...
  },
```

I use `apollo-server-lambda` for communication with my lambda and before I tried to mock some resolvers with predefined data. Then I deployed my lambda and it was ok. After that I used already working service to fetch some data and return it from one of my resolvers and tried to build and deploy my lambda. And I got this error. I didn't install any additional dependencies. So I suppose it is associated with my changes in resolvers or with `esbuild` configuration. But I am not sure. Did anyone face similar issues?

P.S.: Full stack trace:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module './json.js'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module './json.js'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/task/index.js",
    "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
    "- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)",
    "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
  ]
}
enter code here
```

Comment: can you post the whole error reponse and if possible share the lambda code as well?

Comment: @Ruben, Not sure if I can cuz it is a project under NDA) I can only share some parts of the code with changes. But I added stack trace)

Answer (score 0):

This error was associated with `'winston'` package which was used for logging. It cannot be bundled correctly by `esbuild`. So as a workaround for it u can specify `nodeModules: ['winston']` in bundling options in your aws lambda function constructor.